# KDiff3 - ignore or exclude the first 3 characters in a line if they are numeric

Tags: git-extensions, kdiff3

I am using KDiff3 as the diff tool in Git Extensions.
In some of the old projects based on VB6, there are line numbers inserted at the beginning of the line.
If an older version of the code file did not have line numbers, KDiff3 shows differences for each and every line and it makes it almost impossible to find real differences in code.
Is there a way to set KDiff3 so that it will ignore the first 3 characters and if possible only if they are numeric?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dug some more in and found how to set it up in KDiff3. It works almost exactly as I wanted.
Go to Configure -> Diff tab -> check "Ignore numbers treat as white space"
Beatiful